# Error: matrix multiplication: incompatible matrix dimensions: 100x96490 and 96489x22

Tags: r, seurat, harmony

When I am running RunHarmony, it produces this error message. What could this mean? I have ran the same code before and never encountered this error. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Error: matrix multiplication: incompatible matrix dimensions: 100x96490 and 96489x22
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In theta * (1 - exp(-(N_b/(nclust * tau))^2)) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In rbind(rep(1, N), phi) :
number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Code

```r
pbmc_small <- FilterGenes(object = pbmc_small, min.value = 0.5, min.cells = 100)
pbmc_small <- NormalizeData(pbmc_small)
pbmc_small <- FindVariableFeatures(pbmc_small, selection.method = "vst", nfeatures = 2000)
pbmc_small <- ScaleData(pbmc_small, features = rownames(pbmc_small))
pbmc_small <- RunPCA(pbmc_small, features = VariableFeatures(object = pbmc_small))
pbmc_small@meta.data$library_id <- as.factor(pbmc_small@meta.data$library_id)
pbmc_small <- RunHarmony(pbmc_small, group.by.vars="library_id", verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm getting flashbacks to linear algebra, but I don't think matrix multiplication works when the number of columns in the first does not match the number of rows in the second.

Comment: Welcome to SO, claireanjou! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a decent start here, but please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(pbmc_small,20))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.